# Resolving macro variable inside PROC SQL

Tags: sas

I have a macro variable I need to use within PROC SQL. The way it resolves appears to have perfect syntax, but I am getting a syntax error and I'm not sure why;

```
%let test = mytext;
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE myTalbe&test AS
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.column
FROM
    tablename a
WHERE
    a.column = %bquote('&test')
;QUIT;
```

The error I get throws a red line under the resolved text, **'mytext'**, and says

> ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a name, a
>   quoted string, a numeric constant, a datetime constant, 
>                 a missing value, (, *, +, -, ALL, ANY, BTRIM, CALCULATED, CASE, INPUT, PUT, SELECT, SOME, SUBSTRING, TRANSLATE, 
>                 USER.

I don't feel like this error applies here. If I hard code in **'mytext'** it works fine. Am I missing something right under my nose? Can anyone lend me a hand?

Thanks!!!

Comment: We don't encourage use of [tag:enterprise-guide] tag unless you're asking about EG functionality (as opposed to SAS language functionality).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BQUOTE function tries to resolve the value immediately at execution time.  Try removing it and using double quotes instead:

```
%let test = mytext;
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE myTalbe&test AS
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.column
FROM
    tablename a
WHERE
    a.column = "&test"
;QUIT;
```

Comment: This generates the same error, this time showing my desired output with double quotes

Comment: NOTE: Line generated by the macro function "BQUOTE".
77         "mytext"

 This shows up before the error

Comment: apologies yes - `bquote` is a funny one! Answer updated

Comment: I would have swore that I had already done this, and it didn't work. This use of just double quotes appears to be giving me the desired output. Thanks, Allan.

Answer (score 3):

The macro quoting is confusing the SAS parser. For this program I would remove the use of `%bquote()` and just use double quotes instead of single quotes so that the macro variable reference will resolve.

```
WHERE a.column = "&test"
```

If your are actually generating pass thru SQL into a system that requires the use of single quotes for string literals then you will need to use `%unquote()` to remove the macro quoting.

```
... from connection to ... ( ...
WHERE a.column = %unquote(%bquote('&test'))
... ) ...
```

Comment: I always use %bquote without fail when I have pass-throughs. I would have swore I tried double quotes first and I had issues, before posting this issue. I gotta give it to Allan though, since he answered first! Thanks, Tom!